# Where should I install Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, repository

I have separated my project in three different project --

1. project.BL
2. project.Model
3. project.UI

There are 2 options now to install packages --

1. Manage NuGet packeges for solution.
2. Manage NuGet package for separate project.

Now I want to install entity framework in my project, where should I install it?

NOTE: I am using Code-first approach.

I am trying to Enable-Migrations but it gives error

```
The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized ...
```

So I checked installed packages, it doesn't have Entity Framework installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Entity Framework to DataLayer or Business Layer (Layer which interacts with the Database). And secondly you have to install EF in the project.UI and then you have to add connection string also in the Project.UI which needs EF to be installed on Project.UI also.

Comment: What if I use "Manage NuGet packeges for solution", In this case I dont have to worry if EF is installed for project or not

Comment: Yes, you can also do that but I think you should not add extra packages in project where it is not required since it increases size of project and extra dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Entity Framework in the project where your model is living - project.Model

Comment: Hi Andrei! same answer has already been given by @Muhammad. Your answer does not help in anyway.